# How to format text in a <div> to scroll smoothy with an animation?

Tags: css, html, text

I have this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rharrison2641/pmwqy94a/3/). This is an in-progress section of my website. The problem I'm having with the snippet of code is that the text will not size properly when adjusting the CSS percentage values for the height, width, and, most importantly, the top and left positioning. I don't know if my positioning is incorrect or not. I'm not the best at knowing when to use what positions at what specific instances.

CODE:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.Experience_Target {
  display: inline-block;
}

.EXP1Box {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Hangar {
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

#Virtual {
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

.Hangar {
  background: url(https://s8.postimg.cc/d56er2eut/Hangar_Phot.png);
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 75%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Hangar:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}

.NextEra {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  top: 3.5%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -o-transition: .5s ease;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextEra {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0.0%;
  left: 26.3%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 63px;
  color: white;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 64px;
  color: white;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextText1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  left: -18%;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: italic;
}

.NextText1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -300%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextText2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -300%;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%
}

.NextText2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 18%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="EXP1Box">
  <div class="Hangar">
    <div class="NextEra">
      <div class="NextEra">
        <img alt="NextEra" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/h1jqn4zv9/Next_Era_Pop.png" class="NextEra">
      </div>

      <div class="NextText1">
        <h4 class="NextText1">Future Ambitions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="NextText2">
        <h3 class="NextText2">Internship Position With:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Virtual">
  </div>

</section>
```

What I want to happen is for the text to be small and off the page when someone is not hovering over the picture, but to become large and take up half of the side of the image once someone hovers over it - similar to the animation of the NextEra logo on the left. I just can't position any text at the current moment for some weird reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the answer provided solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer (to mark it as solved) by clicking the checkmark that appears when you hover to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I think one option for you would be to use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to hide the text when you don't want to display it, instead of messing with z-indexes and transitions. It wasn't very clear from your code whether you wanted the text to overflow the box when visible.. I positioned it so that it was all in the box. I adjusted the text sizes but if you want them smaller /bigger, you can tweak. I added color (just so I could see where they were to begin with).. again, tweakable.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jxet8uzq/) and snippet:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.Experience_Target {
  display: inline-block;
}

.EXP1Box {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Hangar {
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

#Virtual {
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

.Hangar {
  background: url(https://s8.postimg.cc/d56er2eut/Hangar_Phot.png);
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 75%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;
Really wish I could make this work.
Fucks up because of zoom*/
}

.Hangar:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}

.NextEra {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  top: 3.5%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -o-transition: .5s ease;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextEra {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0.0%;
  left: 26.3%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 63px;
  color: blue;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 64px;
  color: green;
}

.NextText1 {
  color: forestgreen;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: italic;
  visibility: visible;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextText1 {
  /*margin-left: 18%;
  z-index: 2;*/
  visibility: hidden;
}

.Hangar:hover .NextText2 {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 18%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.NextText2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="EXP1Box">
  <div class="Hangar">
    <div class="NextEra">
      <div class="NextEra">
        <img alt="NextEra" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/h1jqn4zv9/Next_Era_Pop.png" class="NextEra">
      </div>
      <div class="NextText1">
        <h4 class="NextText1">Future Ambitions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="NextText2">
        <h3 class="NextText2">Internship Position With:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Virtual">
  </div>

</section>
```